# Explain the logic of the output please

Tags: logic

I am new to C++. I know the output would be 1024, 10.
I just have no clue as to why log would print out 10, instead of 1.

```
int n = 1024;
int log = 0;
for (int i = 1; i < n; i = i * 2);
   log++;
cout << n << " " << log << endl;
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Do you understand the `for` loop? The `log++;` statement is inside the loop.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are missing just the brackets if you are trying to iterate over the loop and print out the log.

```cpp
int n = 1024;
int log = 0;
for (int i = 1; i < n; i = i * 2)
{
  log++;
  cout << n << " " << log << endl;
}
```

Comment: I am aware that there should be a bracket, it is just this was the exact problem in my text book.